# How can I access a directory outside docker context to be able access a nuget/project?

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to up a docker from an existing project to run our integration test. 
The solution file has directory navigation to a folder outside my context configured in docker-compose (build:context). This is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
services:
  integration:
    container_name: backend_integration
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: buildscripts/backend-integration.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

I'm running `docker-compose up integration`

My dockerfile :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./Directory.Build.targets .
COPY ./src/services/{projectName}/project.sln .
COPY ./src/services/{projectName}/{projectName}/projectName.csproj ./{projectName}/
COPY ./src/services/{projectName}/{projectName}Test/projectNameTest.csproj ./{projectName}Test/
COPY ./src/services/{projectName}/{projectName}/nuget.config . 

RUN dotnet restore --configfile nuget.config  // This is where DBCommom and DataEntities were called
```

My solution file (sln) has these references

```
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "projectNameTest", "projectNameTest\projectNameTest.csproj", "{3038F569-2095-4B0D-9531-EF28424E47FB}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "DBCommon", "..\..\..\..\..\pkg\Common\DBCommon\DBCommon.csproj", "{4B4D0CB1-D023-4985-A871-204C43FB2F0A}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "DataEntities", "..\..\..\..\..\pkg\Common\DataEntities\DataEntities.csproj", "{6BAF95C4-667F-4AC4-99EC-EB99DC1DF3B7}"
EndProject
```

PS: the follow error

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.207/NuGet.targets(246,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/pkg/Common/DBCommon/DBCommon.csproj" was not found. [/app/projectName.sln]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.207/NuGet.targets(246,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/pkg/Common/DataEntities/DataEntities.csproj" was not found. [/app/projectName.sln]
ERROR: Service 'integration' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore --configfile nuget.config' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer. You cannot.

A little longer answer:
For Docker, it is always `Dockerfile` and below that Docker can access.
The `COPY` commands in the `Dockerfile` are relative to the current folder.

You might have to re-arrange your project structure. Move your Dockerfile at the root, probably next to the solution file, and adjust all the project references relative to that folder.

You should also focus on `.dockerignore` file and mention all the files/folders that you don't want copied. This'll help you reduce the `context` that gets copied inside the docker image. (generally the first line of `docker build` command).